# Performance difference when calling class methods in model vs controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, model, controller

In my rails app I am fetching a batch of data from the DB with around a million records. I am simply calling the following query combined with some pagination logic, and right now it is working very well. The code is defined in my model, like so:

```
def find_records(current_page, max_records, start_value, end_value)
   where(value_range: start_value..end_value)
        .offset((current_page - 1) * max_records).limit(max_records)
end
```

However, in my previous attempt, I had the following code defined in my model:

```
def find_records(max_records, start_value, end_value)
   where(value_range: start_value..end_value)
end
```

And I called `.offset` and `.limit` inside the controller like so:

```
def index
  current_page = params[:page]
  max_records = 3
  start_value = 4
  end_value = 8
  Model.find_records(start_value, end_value).offset((current_page - 1) * max_records).limit(max_records)
end
```

When I did this, my memory completely gave up on the 3rd or 4th page and my app just crashed. I don't know why calling `.limit` and `.offset` in the model solved the issue.

So my question is, how does calling class methods in your model rather than the controller improve code execution performance? I mean this query is obviously data-related so it makes sense to call it inside the model anyways, but I would still like to know the wonders behind the magic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does calling class methods in your model rather than the controller improve code execution performance?

It should not. Both your queries return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Both `offset` and `limit` are used to build the query, so in both scenarios you should see the same query in your logs. Please check your `development.log` when in doubt.

Having the code query code in your model makes sense. The controller shouldn't know all those details.

About the pagination, there are a few solutions in the rails world - [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari), [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Comment: I checked again, you're absolutely right, it had no difference. I probably had some kind of complicated logic that made it very slow. It was probably a stupid question but thank you very much for answering, will check the log too when in doubt.